# Handling exceptions to JSP page from @Service class

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I am doing Spring MVC, but I don't know how to work with unhandled exceptions. I want to show some custom error text to the user when the exception is thrown in code. I don't want to setup a 404 page in the web.xml, because then all exceptions go to one page and that isn't informative to the user.

This might be a silly example, but I have other code inside my `@Service`-classes which is throwing exceptions.

```
@Controller
public class Control {

    @RequestMapping(value = "something", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String Form(HttpServletRequest request) {
            String name = request.getParameter("name");

            Validate v = Validate();
            v.giveAName(name);
    }

@Service
public class Validate {

    public void giveAName(String name){
    if (name==null) {
        throw new MyException("Name is null");
      } catch (MyException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    //How do I here pass that getMessage value ("Name is null") back to Control-class
    //(and from there to JSP)?
    }      
}

public class MyException extends Exception {
  public MyException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring MVC has two clean and neat ways to deal with exceptions coming from the service layer.

- first at the controller level, you can annotate a method with `@ExceptionHandler`. This method will be called for any `Exception` it declares, can get access to the request, response or session as any other controller method and can return a view name or a `ModelAndView`
- next at the global level (shared by all controllers) you can setup a `HandlerExceptionResolver`. You should notice that by default, `DispatcherServlet` registers a `DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver` to deal with certain standard Spring MVC exceptions.

You will find more details in the [Spring reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-exceptionhandlers)

EDIT : example using `@ExceptionHandler` :

In service layer you simply throw your exceptions :

```
@Service
// as MyException is not a RunTimeException it must be declared
public class Validate throws MyException {

    public void giveAName(String name){
    if (name==null) {
        throw new MyException("Name is null"); // not caught locally ...
    }
}
```

In your controller, you put an exception handler that will catch the exception:

```
@ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
public ModelAndView handler(MyException me){
                ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
                model.addObject("error", me.getMessage());

                return model;
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment! You pushed me to the right direction I think, but I can't still solve it out. Frustrating. What I have now is this: http://pastebin.com/PTByhKsn

Answer (score 1):

I would probably extend `MyException` from `RuntimeException` instead of `Exception`, and then put your try/catch block in the controller.  Then you can catch `MyException` there.  That said, usually error messages in exceptions aren't the best thing to display to a user, so you may want to do something with spring custom error messages.

Comment: I can't put my try/catch block to controller, because it would look awful architecturally.

Comment: @TomJoad Why is that?  Is this a specific exception or a generic one for all of your stuff?